How to create schematic of common mode choke that reflect on Common mode, differential mode and mixed mode?
I aim to create a schematic that can replicate the results exactly as seen in the measured S4P file. I have conducted the measurement using a VNA and am attempting the schematic simulation in CST. However, despite multiple iterations in CST, I am unable to produce a proper schematic that accurately reflects common mode insertion loss, differential mode insertion loss, and mixed mode conversion loss. My graphs are not aligning properly. Could you assist me with this issue? Your valuable suggestions would be greatly appreciated.I'm attaching the schematic here( Then center part{represented in blue  color}responsible for changes in common mode insertion loss, and the  left and right part{represented in orange color} is responsible for changes in differential mode insertion loss.

I did multiple iterations and got a good result for Common mode insertion loss

Green graph: Measured result
purple graph: Schematic result
Differential Mode:

Purple colour:Schematic graph
Green: Measured graph
Mixed Mode:
But I'm not getting a proper result for mode conversion! I have tried to change some values of the schematic fro creating asymmetry and mode conversion. but still I'm not getting much improvement.

S75: Schematic result
S31: Measured graph

What function do the two quadripoles at the two ends have? Excuse my ignorance, thanks.

Don't you need a ground wire and some components (capacitive) between any active wire and ground?

What are the coupling factors (if any) of the inductive elements in your circuit? || @Antonio51: I assume this is an RF test bench where any given node is measured as a port with respect to ideal ground, thus testing the component as a four-port, but this would be good for OP to clarify.

@Franc: The left and right RLC Network modelling  the differential mode insertion loss .

@Antonio51: Can you explain more about it?

@TimWilliams: coupling factor is equal to 0.9 in this case. How can it affect mode conversion? why it is difficult to model mode conversion and differential mode at the same time?

0.9 between what? (Note: there are no designators on your schematic.) Is this a value you have fixed, or is it a parameter in the solution?  Might CST be having trouble solving the model because there are extra differential elements, i.e. too many degrees of freedom?  Or not enough, because you've fixed some parameters?

@TimWilliams Thank you for your input ,I would like to clarify the coupling factor , it is  0.9 coupling in  between two center Inductors marked 1-2.
